# What is this type called (Swift)? var something = [(item1: String, item2: Float, item3: [String])]()

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, filtering

I have been working with this type of element for a while to populate a bunch of data in each cell in tableviews. Can anyone tell me what this data type is called? `Items = [(category:String, items: [String], price: [Float])]()`

I am also experiencing some problems with unwrapping and filtering the content inside of this element. When I print `Items`, it returns something like this: `[("Beef", ["Steak", "Deep fried beef"], [5.98999977, 4.98999977]), ("Chicken", ["Roast chicken"], [4.98999977])]`

The problem is that I can't access `items` array inside `Items`.

I can easily filter the content of the tableview based on the category with this command:

```
func filteredContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "ALL") {
    Items2 = Items.filter { (element:(category: String, items: [String], price: [Float])) -> Bool in

        return element.category.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But when I want to filter the content like below, I get this error `Value of type '[String]' has no member 'lowercased'`:

```
func filteredContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "ALL") {
        items = items2.filter { (element:(category: String, items: [String], price: [Float])) -> Bool in

            return element.items.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

How can I unwrap the strings in the array of `items`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[String]` means an array of `String` objects. So you can't do `lowercased()` on it. On each on of them, YES, but not on an array of it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your first question is that it is a bit of an odd data type, but it is an `Array` of `Tuple`s consisting of 3 elements: a `String` (`category`), an `Array<String>` (`items`), and an `Array<Float>` (`price`).

To access a single element of the tuple is the same as a regular array. `Items2[0]` for instance. That will give you an `item` that you can access the tuple members on individually. This can be done anonymously (`item.0`, `item.1`, and `item.2`) or via named elements (`item.category`, `item.items`, and `item.price`).

If you access `item.items` (`item.1`), you have a `Array<String>`. Since it is an array of strings, there is no `lowercased`. You can access an individual string in this array and `lowercase` it or join all the strings together into a single string and `lowercase` that.